# Drag sprite with mouse/touch on UE4

Tags: unreal-engine4, blueprint

I want to move the sprite to the release position of the mouse left button. The problem is OnRelease event is fired when the mouse button is release while the mouse is over the sprite. i want to somehow fire an event when the mouse left button released anywhere in the scene after i actually clicked on the sprite.

Answer (score 0):

You shold try to record that you have actually clicked on the sprite. For example, a boolean variable in your player controller.